# Take a toll on X versus take a toil on X

Tags: word-usage, difference

> "Your majesty, the princess is just tired from using too much
> strength... also, the silver she came in contact with took a toil on
> her!"

I see both, but just realized they don't mean the same thing. Or am I wrong? However, they're used to mean the same thing, but toil doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: Can you double check whether _toil_ is a typo for _toll_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Toll* is correct.  I think *toil* must just be a typographical error.  She might have got tired from excessive toil, but the assertion is that the silver took a toll.